# Set base image as small and thumbnail

Tags: magento2

I have nearly 20k products and all images have been set to base only. If i go into backend and then set each image one by one to thumbnail and small as well, it will take me forever.
Is there any way to do it via programming or database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its Magento 2.2.1 site.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look into talbe `eav_attribute`, you will find out the (image,small_image,thumbnail) attribute. In magento 2.1.8, it take the id (87,88,89)
[image]

Use this command below:

```
 UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mgv.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (87, 88, 89)
AND mgv.position = 1;
```

***EDIT***:
If the query doesn't work, It means you have not had the small and thumbnail before, use this code:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(ProductFactory $productFactory){
     $this->_productFactory   = $productFactory;
}

//Change the image
$productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $product) {
    $imagePath = $product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getFirstItem()->getFile();
    if ($imagePath) {
       $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')->updateAttributes([0 => $product->getId()], array("thumbnail" => $imagePath,"small_image" => $imagePath), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is for magento 1 i think, didn't work for me.
Error:
SQL query:


UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (87, 88, 89)
AND mgv.position = 1
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'mg.entity_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Ah, change the `mg.entity` to `mgv.entity`. Don't forget to backup database firrst

Comment: Query ran successfully, what i found it set the base image as small too but not thumbnail.

Comment: I think it did not work, because the product i created for this purpose to test has only base, it didn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Where do i put this code, can you help me with path?

Comment: You can push it in a controller of custom module

Comment: update query works for me

Comment: hi @NeroPhung I want to set the base image as per small image.

Comment: What If I want to make Thumbnail Image as Base and small like one image should be made as base , small and thumnail